# Azure-databricks display function is not showing plotting options

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am a bit stumped on why the display function in Databricks notebook is not showing the plotting options. The popular plotting tabs do not appear at the end. Neither does the column scroller. I have tried extending the window or making it small. And only displaying 5 rows at a time. The Dataframe IS NOT EMPTY.

Additionally using `df.head(10)` or `display(df)` function yields an extremely small window which is unviewable. I usually workaround this problem by modifying the window via Chrome inspect and changing the scale values.

I am running 5.5 Conda Beta (includes Apache Spark 2.4.3, Scala 2.11) cluster and the latest version of chrome.

I have checked the dataframe is not empty. And I am running the latest version of Chrome and Firefox.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCVpG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

What kind of plot are you looking for? What is type(df)? A pandas dataframe? Please be a little bit more specific next time! :)

If you want the generic databricks figure, the easiest way would be to perform some kind of aggregates and/or other manipulations like follows: 
display(diamonds_df.select("color","price").groupBy("color").agg(avg("price")))

Another way is just to call df. Then, click on the bottom left where it will have the visualizations button as shown here: https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/visualizations/index.html#id7

Similarly, if you create a sql query. The cell will render the data result as a table, which you can click on to get the visualization button and create visualizations there.

Lastly, if you have a plot that results in HTML, you will need to use displayHTML() function.

[Source](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/visualizations/index.html%5C)

Comment: it is a Koalas dataframe (logically equivalent to Pandas but underlying structure is Spark).    Additionally databricks offers a display function which I want to utilize. I am unsure as to why i don't have the functionality. The type of plot is irrelevant as I can use external libraries to do the plotting. The whole point of display is to have the plotting feature enabled, which is absent in my case.

Comment: As outlined in the docs, the display function should work with both Pandas and Koalas. 

https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/visualizations/index.html. 

Also, why is there a scaling issue of the outputted frame being practically invisible. A user shouldn't have to go into HTML code of a browser and find the scale feature to properly view an output. I have to do this for every output.

I have followed every step of the doc, including using just df. And the result is the same super small window with no tabs in the bottom left or right. 

I have no purpose for using displayHTML()

Comment: so in the bottom left picture where it shows the table and display(df), does it give you the option of the graph button?

Comment: please look at the attached image. as stated and shown, the option is absent. The only way i have access to those tabs is to convert the dataframe to spark dataframe using to_spark(). And on 40GB of data, this is an expensive operation